# How to make ubuntu OS backup with current setting

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I have installed Ubuntu 10.4 with all preferred setting.

Is there any way i can back that up in a cd so that if want to install that in another machine all the setting and packages are installed as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with Back In Time

Its similar to "Last Good time configuration".You can take that configuration and move it to new host easily
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/back-in-time-a-simple-backup-tool-for-ubuntu.html

Comment: Its not doing anything , i added root folder i.e "/"  to backup but when i click on take snapshot , and when i go to the snapshot locations the folder is empty. how can i check if it has backed anything up